# "not--very much" as "a little"

Tags: word-choice

**You don't study very much.**

> Can I write this sentence as "You study a little"?
>   I think "not--very much" is the same with  "a little".

Answer (score 2):

The "*not very* -adjective" structure is not unique to English, as a roundabout way to say the opposite of the adjective but with less emphasis.  Consider the following series (from smallest to largest):

> That building is tiny.
>
> That's a very small building.
>
> That's a small building.
>
> That building is kind of small.
>
> That building isn't very tall.
>
> That's a pretty tall building.
>
> That's a tall building.
>
> That's a very tall building.
>
> That building is gigantic.

This structure also implies some degree of *expectation*, "This building isn't very tall," suggests that I thought it would be taller.  "He's not a very nice person," suggests that I expected him to be nicer, or that I expected someone like him would be nicer, or that I think he should act nicer than he does.

Similarly, "you don't study very much," suggests that I think you *could* or *would* or *should* study more, but that you don't.  So it's more nuanced than "You study a little."

As with many sentences, context is key to understanding *exactly* what I might mean.

[Edit]  To be clear the "not very X" structure implies something is contrary to expectation, but *not* necessarily as a negative.  "I'm really impressed that you don't study very much, yet you get such good grades!" is totally different from, "No wonder you're failing; you don't study very much."

Comment: I don't think *not [very] much* inherently implies anything at all about expectations or exhortations. If I say *John doesn't do much* you might suppose I think he should do more, but that hardly applies if I say *John doesn't argue much* (where I probably *don't* think that he should argue more). And *John doesn't eat much* could be approving *(...so it doesn't cost much to feed him)* or disapproving *(...which is why he's so weak and sickly)*. Or it could just be an objective assessment of the amount John eats - that's all the words themselves convey.

Comment: @FumbleFingers what about when you include the "very"?  If someone says, "this burger is not very big" I can't help but think they expected it to be bigger, and are surprised, or perhaps you're apologetic that it's not larger when you serve it.  Similarly "John doesn't eat very much" suggests either that the speaker expects John would eat more, or that the listener might expect John would eat more.

Comment: I suppose it's at least *possible* that statistically speaking, *not very much* occurs more often in negative assessments than positive ones (but I certainly wouldn't take that as a given, without evidence). But my point is that even if it were true, this wouldn't imply those specific words have negative associations *in and of themselves*. If that were the case, we'd find usages like *it didn't cost very much* either weird or inherently condemnatory (but we obviously *don't*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not trying to say it's *negative* as much as it's *contrary to expectation*.  "It didn't cost very much" says to me that the speaker and/or the listener expected it to cost more, but not that they think it's cheap or otherwise not worth the price.

Comment: I've made a "non-edit" so I could cancel my downvote. I think I was misled into supposing that your *contrary to expectation* inevitably implied negative ***lower** than expected* (when what we wanted was *more*). But you're right and I was wrong - *not very X* invariably implies *less X than you might **expect***, even though it doesn't always imply *less X than you might **want***.

Answer (score -1):

You don't study very much.

You study a little.

The sentences are not the same in English. If you don't study VERY MUCH, you still are studying A LITTLE.